# jaxb-generate classes from wsdl ,each schema classes should go to corrsponding package

Tags: jaxb, wsdl, schema, jax-ws, wsdl2java

i  have one wsdl file which have schhemas included in it, i want to generate java classes for each schema in different package,please help me.

i have used following code,its generating classes related to all schemas

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0"     
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="Event.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">         
<jaxb:schemaBindings>             

<jaxb:package name="com.event.dto" />

 <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
       <jaxb:typeName suffix="CHASE"/>
 </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
```

Answer (score 1):

For each shema file add `xml` like in your question, but with different name of

```
<jaxb:package name="com.event.dto" />
```